# Flash Can't Access PHP Script?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

HI,

I have a flash application (working demo [here](http://www.userbooth.com/demo/)) which I'm using to let users take pictures of themselves on my website. The application takes the picture, then lets the user save it by invoking a PHP script located in the same directory as the Flash file.

Testing this on my local machine works fine - the picture saves as intended. However, once on my server, the saving no longer works. The flash runs fine - pictures can be taken, however the save button does not work. Why would the environments differ in such a specific way, and what might be preventing the save function from working?

Comment: You may want to clarify how the PHP script is invoked by your flash application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need to make the permissions on the directory you want to save the image into writeable. Typically, the default setting for most hosting companies is read only. This will probably be in your hosting companies control panel.